# What are the most common Chinese terms for travel power adapters between different international socket and plug standards?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

Are there more specific terms than “適配器” which is the general word for “adapter”? What about “轉換器”?

[image: various travel adapters]

English speakers use a variety of terms to refer to these devices. Personally I find "travel adapter" pretty unambiguous and straightforward.

[image: various travel adapters (image on Chinese internet)]

Comment: I think what you are talking about maybe 插排 or 变压器,I am in China,and I can't see the pictures you put in the links.So I guess it.

Comment: @Whhhhhhhhy: [Link to similar image on Chinese internet](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/c31737db-b9b3-49fa-a60a-41ceb8647f53_1.7c91f3db9dcd45120bd0ace5cb9455ae.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF). I think 变压器 might mean "transformer" and be used for devices that convert between 110 and 240 volts. Most travel adapters only convert the shape of the plug/socket since most modern devices accept either voltage and adapting voltage makes heavier and more expensive adapters.

Comment: @Whhhhhhhhy: 插排 seems to refer to what in English would be called a powerboard or powerstrip. For now I'm looking for the term that just converts a single outlet/plug but it's great to also know this term!

Comment: now I can see the picture,but I haven't use it before.

Comment: It is called 插头转换器.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[「转换插头」](https://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E8%BD%AC%E6%8D%A2%E6%8F%92%E5%A4%B4&commend=all&ssid=s5-e&search_type=item&sourceId=tb.index&spm=a21bo.50862.201856-taobao-item.1&ie=utf8&initiative_id=tbindexz_20161020) just as printed on the picture you provided.

Or, less commonly, 「插座转换器」「电源插座转换器」, etc.

Comment: I looked at so many pictures trying to find a good one that I didn't even get around to trying to work out the characters (-:

Comment: This worked perfectly by the way. I thought I lost my adapter at a cafe. I asked them if they had it and they understood my first attempt and pulled it out of a drawer for me (-: